# How to json_normalize nested json arrays

Tags: pandas, json-normalize

I have the complex json structure as below.   I am able to json_normalize only first level of array (MatchingReleases.MatchingRelease).  whereas I have one more json array which is not getting normalized (MatchingTheatres.MatchingTheatre.HhMatchingTheatre.Theatre.HhSalaries.Salary) as I am getting Nan even though the respective levels have values.  Not sure if there are any limitations in json normalize with respect to the number of levels.   Should I give any more meta information?

My approach:

```
matchingReleaseDf = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(dataSourceOutputDict["MovieEnquiryResponseType"], 
        record_path =  ["MatchingReleases", "MatchingRelease"], meta = ["MatchingReleases", "MatchingRelease", "MatchingTheatres", "MatchingTheatre", "Theatre", "HHSalaries", "Salary"],
        errors = "ignore"))
```

```
{
    "MovieEnquiryResponseType": {
        "SearchedMovie": {
            "SearchElements": {
                "Movie": {
                    "MoviePartName1": "Home",
                    "MoviePartName2": "Alone",
                    "DateReleased": "1973-03-07T00:00:00"
                },
                "Address": {
                    "AddressValidation": "AsInput",
                    "Unformatted": {
                        "Line1": "456",
                        "Line2": "Foxhall Road",
                        "Line3": "Newyork",
                        "Line4": null,
                        "Line5": null,
                        "Line6": null,
                        "PostCode": "44306",
                        "Country": "United States"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "MatchingReleases": {
            "MatchingRelease": [
                {
                    "ReleaseInfo": {
                        "ReleaseNumber": "1",
                        "ReleaseDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00"
                    },
                    "MatchingTheatres": {
                        "MatchingTheatre": {
                            "MatchInfo": {
                                "MatchingTheatreId": "408794d4-a5e8-4ca1-b53a-320103e23b1f",
                                "MatchType": "F",
                                "LinkedAddressMatch": "false"
                            },
                            "HhMatchingTheatre": {
                                "MatchingMovie": {
                                    "MovieRole": "PH",
                                    "MovieNumber": "1",
                                    "MovieCode": "D"
                                },
                                "Theatre": {
                                    "Provider": {
                                        "ContactDetails": "01473 212422||-",
                                        "ProducerId": "I12434",
                                        "ProducerDescription": "RedJeyant",
                                        "DelAutId": "I12434",
                                        "DelAutDescription": "RedJeyant",
                                        "DelAutType": "2"
                                    },
                                    "Production": {
                                        "ProductionType": "A",
                                        "ProductionNumber": "123123",
                                        "CollectiveProductionIndicator": "N",
                                        "ProductionNumberID": "Standard",
                                        "InceptionDate": "2021-06-01T00:00:00Z",
                                        "PeriodEndDate": "2021-11-05T00:00:00Z",
                                        "RiskAddress": {
                                            "HouseNr": "456",
                                            "Street1": "Foxhall Road",
                                            "City": "Newyork",
                                            "County": "Suffolk",
                                            "PostCode": "44306",
                                            "Country": "United States",
                                            "AddressValidation": "PafValid"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "TheatreDetails": {
                                        "TheatreNr": "50000",
                                        "LossCause": "10",
                                        "TheatreStatus": "O1",
                                        "LossDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00Z",
                                        "LossSetupDate": "2021-10-02T00:00:00Z",
                                        "ReleaseDescription": "This is a test Theatre by Lorenz",
                                        "CatastropheRelated": "U"
                                    },
                                    "HhSalaries": {
                                        "Salary": [
                                            {
                                                "SalaryCode": "A",
                                                "SalaryAmount": "100.00"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "SalaryCode": "M",
                                                "SalaryAmount": "100.00"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "Movies": {
                                        "ProductionHolders": {
                                            "ProductionHolder": {
                                                "MovieCode": "D",
                                                "MovieNumber": "1",
                                                "Person": {
                                                    "Name": {
                                                        "Title": "1",
                                                        "MoviePartName1": "Home",
                                                        "MoviePartName2": "Theatre",
                                                        "DateReleased": "1973-03-07T00:00:00Z",
                                                        "Gender": "M"
                                                    },
                                                    "Address": {
                                                        "HouseNr": "456",
                                                        "Street1": "Foxhall Road",
                                                        "City": "Newyork",
                                                        "County": "Suffolk",
                                                        "PostCode": "44306",
                                                        "Country": "United States",
                                                        "AddressValidation": "PafValid"
                                                    },
                                                    "Email": "thisisatest@testers.avm.com",
                                                    "BankDetails": {
                                                        "SortCode": "567832",
                                                        "AccountNumber": "8976543"
                                                    },
                                                    "SalaryAmount": "123.00"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ReleaseInfo": {
                        "ReleaseNumber": "2",
                        "ReleaseDate": "2021-10-02T00:00:00"
                    },
                    "MatchingTheatres": {
                        "MatchingTheatre": {
                            "MatchInfo": {
                                "MatchingTheatreId": "3d491762-c25c-406b-8870-6785d7e8a408",
                                "MatchType": "F",
                                "LinkedAddressMatch": "false"
                            },
                            "HhMatchingTheatre": {
                                "MatchingMovie": {
                                    "MovieRole": "PH",
                                    "MovieNumber": "1",
                                    "MovieCode": "D"
                                },
                                "Theatre": {
                                    "Provider": {
                                        "ContactDetails": "01473 212422||-",
                                        "ProducerId": "I12434",
                                        "ProducerDescription": "RedJeyant",
                                        "DelAutId": "I12434",
                                        "DelAutDescription": "RedJeyant",
                                        "DelAutType": "2"
                                    },
                                    "Production": {
                                        "ProductionType": "B",
                                        "ProductionNumber": "7567",
                                        "CollectiveProductionIndicator": "N",
                                        "ProductionNumberID": "Standard",
                                        "InceptionDate": "2021-09-26T00:00:00Z",
                                        "PeriodEndDate": "2021-12-11T00:00:00Z",
                                        "RiskAddress": {
                                            "HouseNr": "456",
                                            "Street1": "Foxhall Road",
                                            "City": "Newyork",
                                            "County": "Suffolk",
                                            "PostCode": "44306",
                                            "Country": "United States",
                                            "AddressValidation": "PafValid"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "TheatreDetails": {
                                        "TheatreNr": "50001",
                                        "LossCause": "11",
                                        "TheatreStatus": "O1",
                                        "LossDate": "2021-10-02T00:00:00Z",
                                        "LossSetupDate": "2021-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                                        "ReleaseDescription": "This is a second Theatre by Lorenz",
                                        "CatastropheRelated": "U"
                                    },
                                    "HhSalaries": {
                                        "Salary": [
                                            {
                                                "SalaryCode": "B",
                                                "SalaryAmount": "200.00"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "SalaryCode": "G",
                                                "SalaryAmount": "200.00"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "Movies": {
                                        "ProductionHolders": {
                                            "ProductionHolder": {
                                                "MovieCode": "D",
                                                "MovieNumber": "1",
                                                "Person": {
                                                    "Name": {
                                                        "Title": "1",
                                                        "MoviePartName1": "Home",
                                                        "MoviePartName2": "Theatre",
                                                        "DateReleased": "1973-03-07T00:00:00Z",
                                                        "Gender": "M"
                                                    },
                                                    "Address": {
                                                        "HouseNr": "456",
                                                        "Street1": "Foxhall Road",
                                                        "City": "Newyork",
                                                        "County": "Suffolk",
                                                        "PostCode": "44306",
                                                        "Country": "United States",
                                                        "AddressValidation": "PafValid"
                                                    },
                                                    "Email": "thisisatest@testers.avm.com",
                                                    "BankDetails": {
                                                        "SortCode": "110000",
                                                        "AccountNumber": "20658200"
                                                    },
                                                    "SalaryAmount": "456.00"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ReleaseInfo": {
                        "ReleaseNumber": "3",
                        "ReleaseDate": "2021-10-03T00:00:00"
                    },
                    "MatchingTheatres": {
                        "MatchingTheatre": {
                            "MatchInfo": {
                                "MatchingTheatreId": "822838f9-927a-4e40-91ff-815e3f75b75b",
                                "MatchType": "F",
                                "LinkedAddressMatch": "false"
                            },
                            "HhMatchingTheatre": {
                                "MatchingMovie": {
                                    "MovieRole": "PH",
                                    "MovieNumber": "1",
                                    "MovieCode": "D"
                                },
                                "Theatre": {
                                    "Provider": {
                                        "ContactDetails": "235678123||-",
                                        "ProducerId": "I12434",
                                        "ProducerDescription": "RedJeyant",
                                        "DelAutId": "I12434",
                                        "DelAutDescription": "RedJeyant",
                                        "DelAutType": "2"
                                    },
                                    "Production": {
                                        "ProductionType": "H",
                                        "ProductionNumber": "657567",
                                        "CollectiveProductionIndicator": "N",
                                        "ProductionNumberID": "Standard",
                                        "InceptionDate": "2021-10-01T00:00:00Z",
                                        "PeriodEndDate": "2021-11-04T00:00:00Z",
                                        "RiskAddress": {
                                            "HouseNr": "456",
                                            "Street1": "Foxhall Road",
                                            "City": "Newyork",
                                            "County": "Suffolk",
                                            "PostCode": "44306",
                                            "Country": "United States",
                                            "AddressValidation": "PafValid"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "TheatreDetails": {
                                        "TheatreNr": "50002",
                                        "LossCause": "12",
                                        "TheatreStatus": "O1",
                                        "LossDate": "2021-10-03T00:00:00Z",
                                        "LossSetupDate": "2021-10-12T00:00:00Z",
                                        "ReleaseDescription": "This is a third Theatre by Lorenz",
                                        "CatastropheRelated": "U"
                                    },
                                    "HhSalaries": {
                                        "Salary": [
                                            {
                                                "SalaryCode": "D",
                                                "SalaryAmount": "300.00"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "SalaryCode": "E",
                                                "SalaryAmount": "300.00"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "Movies": {
                                        "ProductionHolders": {
                                            "ProductionHolder": {
                                                "MovieCode": "D",
                                                "MovieNumber": "1",
                                                "Person": {
                                                    "Name": {
                                                        "Title": "1",
                                                        "MoviePartName1": "Home",
                                                        "MoviePartName2": "Theatre",
                                                        "DateReleased": "1973-03-07T00:00:00Z",
                                                        "Gender": "M"
                                                    },
                                                    "Address": {
                                                        "HouseNr": "456",
                                                        "Street1": "Foxhall Road",
                                                        "City": "Newyork",
                                                        "County": "Suffolk",
                                                        "PostCode": "44306",
                                                        "Country": "United States",
                                                        "AddressValidation": "PafValid"
                                                    },
                                                    "Email": "thisisatest@testers.avm.com",
                                                    "BankDetails": {
                                                        "SortCode": "110203",
                                                        "AccountNumber": "20658211"
                                                    },
                                                    "SalaryAmount": "789.00"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need `record_path`

```py
matchingReleaseDf = pd.json_normalize(dataSourceOutputDict["MovieEnquiryResponseType"],
                                      record_path = ["MatchingReleases", "MatchingRelease"],
                                      errors = "ignore")
```

To flatten `salary` column, you can

```py
matchingReleaseDf = matchingReleaseDf.explode('MatchingTheatres.MatchingTheatre.HhMatchingTheatre.Theatre.HhSalaries.Salary').reset_index()

salary = pd.json_normalize(matchingReleaseDf['MatchingTheatres.MatchingTheatre.HhMatchingTheatre.Theatre.HhSalaries.Salary']).add_prefix('MatchingTheatres.MatchingTheatre.HhMatchingTheatre.Theatre.HhSalaries.Salary.')

out = pd.concat([matchingReleaseDf, salary], axis=1).drop('MatchingTheatres.MatchingTheatre.HhMatchingTheatre.Theatre.HhSalaries.Salary', axis=1)
```

Comment: If I give only record_path = ["MatchingReleases", "MatchingRelease"], json array Salary is not normalized.   It comes as Json array itself